# Is it possible to generate a if statement with a variable validation?

Tags: jquery, validation, variables, dynamic

As the title suggest i'm generating a if validation with a script. So the if statement would be adjusted based on the given array(should function as a config file). 
Let me give you an example:

```
 if(sTime == "12:00:00")
 {
   //code to happen when it's 12 o'clock
 }
```

The config input should be "12:00:00". That's fine. But what if there are more times in the config file? 

With 2 times the if statement should be :

```
 if(sTime == "12:00:00" || sTime == "12:30:00")
 {
   //code to happen when it's 12 o'clock
 }
```

To let this happen automatically i generate the validation myself based on the config input.

Here is my generate code:

```
var tijd = ["12:00:00", "12:30:00"];
var validatie = '';

var length = tijd.length;
$.each(tijd, function(key, value)
{
    if(length != key+1)
    {
        if(length > 1)
        {
            validatie += 'sTime =="' + value + '" || ';
        }
        else
        {
            validatie += 'sTime =="' + value + '"';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        validatie += 'sTime =="' + value + '"';
    }
})
```

In this case the value of my validation will be: sTime == "12:00:00" || sTime == "12:30:00" 
 That looks exactly as it should be! However how do i use this as a code? It is now stored as a string.

```
if(validatie)
{
  //will only check if the array exists
}
```

How can i excecute this variable? 
 Any help is appreciated!
**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmzdb/)**

 
**This is all in jquery, may you not notice**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the intended validation is literally "The value of `sTime` matches one of the elements in this array" then you can just do:

```
if(tijd.indexOf(sTime) > -1) {
    // code here
}
```

Or, if for some reason your browser doesn't support that, there's a jQuery function:

```
if($.inArray(sTime, tijd)) {
    // code here
}
```

There shouldn't be any need to generate an `if` statements condition as a string and then attempt to execute it as part of the code.

If you absolutely did have to (and I would strongly suggest **not** doing this), you could use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
if(eval(validatie)) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: IndexOf, ofcourse thank you! great of you giving more possibilities! :) As i would rather not use the eval function, as you also suggested.